# Get My Documents folder path in delphi

Tags: delphi, directory

i use the following code to get special directories

```
uses
  ActiveX, ShlObj;

{...}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
// Replace CSIDL_HISTORY with the constants below
var
  Allocator: IMalloc;
  SpecialDir: PItemIdList;
  FBuf: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  PerDir: string;
begin
  if SHGetMalloc(Allocator) = NOERROR then
  begin
    SHGetSpecialFolderLocation(Form1.Handle, CSIDL_PERSONAL, SpecialDir);
    SHGetPathFromIDList(SpecialDir, @FBuf[0]);
    Allocator.Free(SpecialDir);
    ShowMessage(string(FBuf));
  end;
end;
```

And now i want to get the my documents path 
so i use 
mydocfolderpath := string(FBuf) + '\Documents'   and i think it works well
but my doubt is this the mydocuments path on all windows PCs (personalfolder/documents) can the user change this stucture and make my documents folder anywhare else (eg: c:\documents)
if the user an change the path give me a proper way and i like to know what is the name of mydocuments folder (My Documents or Documents)

Comment: Be aware that some version of Windows use localized path names. Unless you are completely sure what version and language you're running on, never add a "special" folder name as a string constant in English or whatever language. It may not be the correct name on the target system. Always use one of the specific CSIDL_ or their newer equivalent.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CSIDL_PERSONAL **is** the My Documents folder:

> CSIDL_PERSONAL FOLDERID_Documents
>   Version 6.0. The virtual folder that
>   represents the My Documents desktop
>   item. This is equivalent to
>   CSIDL_MYDOCUMENTS.
>
> Previous to Version 6.0. The file
>   system directory used to physically
>   store a user's common repository of
>   documents. A typical path is
>   C:\Documents and Settings\username\My
>   Documents. This should be
>   distinguished from the virtual My
>   Documents folder in the namespace. To
>   access that virtual folder, use
>   SHGetFolderLocation, which returns the
>   ITEMIDLIST for the virtual location,
>   or refer to the technique described in
>   Managing the File System.Managing the File System.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494(VS.85).aspx for a list and description of all CSIDL constants available

Answer (score 29):

If you are using a recent version of Delphi (XE5 or greater) then you can use the new platform agnostic classes.  Basically include `System.IOUtils` in your `uses` then use `TPath.GetDocumentsPath` to get the documents folder.

Check out the [Doc Wiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Standard_RTL_Path_Functions_across_the_Supported_Target_Platforms)